# Address Form Inputs: Text vs Select/Dropdown (Dependent)

Tags: website-design, forms, input, input-fields, ux-designer

I know it's common to let the users type in their address, city, province, etc.

I found this website (local one) that uses dropdowns.

- First it will ask your province
- Then the city/municipal dropdown will become active containing cities from the selected province
- Then the other dropdown that contains divisions of that city will become active.

Which one of them is usable? We are in a local context only.

Why or why not the first/second one? Which one has a better UX?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is accuracy and reducing errors, then the second one (dynamic dropdown lists) is better. If the goal is speed, then the first one (let user type) is better. There is lots of articles online about dropdown lists not being ideal. The main reason is that it takes a (1) click (2) scroll down a long list (3) select. Most users can type pretty fast these days, and auto-correction usually fixes any typos. The HTML5 datalist element is a hybrid approach, where the user can start typing the first few characters, and the list will only show the valid options. Not perfect, but it gives users a sense of what is accepted as the valid selection.

Comment: how about a dropdown with search? At least that'll will them type for speed and shows only the valid selections. Speed + Accuracy. Thanks for the suggestion that helped

Comment: When you say a dropdown with search, do you mean something similar to an autocomplete element?

Comment: The autocomplete text field is an effective way to accomplish both goals of balancing speed and accuracy. The most well known example is the Google search page. We all use it and we don't give it a second thought.